# Everytime I try to install a package using pip it shows an error

Tags: python-3.x

Installing jupyter notebook. Everytime the same error occurs. And the error is the same if I install any other package too. I am currently using python 3.6.5 version which is the latest one. I have recently downloaded python and my windows version is 10.

```
>pip install jupyter
Collecting jupyter
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/df/0f5dd132200728a86190397e1ea87cd76244e42d39ec5e88efd25b2abd7e/jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipywidgets (from jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/24/fabc09ad81c6071159a4d12d5bfbddcbea69bd9e3b16c3250ef300c0285f/ipywidgets-7.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipykernel (from jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/3f/cd624c835aa3336a9110d0a99e15070f343b881b7d651ab1375ef226a3ac/ipykernel-4.8.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting notebook (from jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/66/cfed59f574d03ca5f1b7c5281485a9cc9a0f21342d24e0f057572316dae5/notebook-5.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-console (from jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/82/6469cd7fccf7958cbe5dce2e623f1e3c5e27f1bb1ad36d90519bc2d5d370/jupyter_console-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting qtconsole (from jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/ff/047e0dca2627b162866920e7aa93f04523c0ae81e5c67060eec85701992d/qtconsole-4.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nbconvert (from jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/ea/280d6c0d92f8e3ca15fd798bbcc2ea141489f9539de7133d8fe10ea4b049/nbconvert-5.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting widgetsnbextension~=3.2.0 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/fa/64acc09fc845a6b2dc0724d6f3f81e829b778ed5e9a7559567b4f19a3f4b/widgetsnbextension-3.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipython>=4.0.0; python_version >= "3.3" (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b1/7f/91d50f28af3e3a24342561983a7857e399ce24093876e6970b986a0b6677/ipython-6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nbformat>=4.2.0 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/27/9a654d2b6cc1eaa517d1c5a4405166c7f6d72f04f6e7eea41855fe808a46/nbformat-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting traitlets>=4.3.1 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/d6/abcb22de61d78e2fc3959c964628a5771e47e7cc60d53e9342e21ed6cc9a/traitlets-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-client (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/dd/fe6c4d683b09eb05342bd2816b7779663f71762b4fa9c2d5203d35d17354/jupyter_client-5.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tornado>=4.0 (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F5B1BF66D8>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/3d/4a/5b321dc86dec06205cfae8e06fd9fa78be57e199b8665dc152c56f7d5b53/tornado-5.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F5B1CF3A20>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/3d/4a/5b321dc86dec06205cfae8e06fd9fa78be57e199b8665dc152c56f7d5b53/tornado-5.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F5B1CF3A90>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/3d/4a/5b321dc86dec06205cfae8e06fd9fa78be57e199b8665dc152c56f7d5b53/tornado-5.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F5B1CF3E10>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/3d/4a/5b321dc86dec06205cfae8e06fd9fa78be57e199b8665dc152c56f7d5b53/tornado-5.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F5B1CF3AC8>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/3d/4a/5b321dc86dec06205cfae8e06fd9fa78be57e199b8665dc152c56f7d5b53/tornado-5.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/3d/4a/5b321dc86dec06205cfae8e06fd9fa78be57e199b8665dc152c56f7d5b53/tornado-5.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F5B1CF38D0>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)'))
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not an issue with pip,it's an error with your firewall/network. Try allowing python3.exe through the firewall and run the terminal as an administrator. I just ran `pip install jupyter` in my terminal, it installed perfectly.

Also update your pip with

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Also, run

```
ping files.pythonhosted.org
```

in your terminal to make sure you can connect

Comment: I had a similar connection error. Upgrading pip solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help people. It was a silly fault at my side. I accidentally messed up my PATH variable.
It's working just fine now after I corrected the path. :)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jason I had accidentally removed my PATH environment variable. After fixing it back to normal everything worked out to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I could install packages using:
`pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>`

according this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29751768/6398487

Answer (score 0):

This seems be to be a known issue with `pip`. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5309.

I suggest you install [`Anaconda`](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux), it will take care of all these dependencies. It comes preinstalled with `jupyter` and some other python libraries like `numpy`, `pandas`.